# Spark RDD foreachPartition to S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am currently exploring Spark. I am faced with the following task - get an RDD, partition it based on a certain criteria and then write multiple files in different folders in a S3 bucket.

Everything is fine until we come to the uploading to S3 part. I've read all the questions relsted to this problem on SO and found that I could either use `AmazonS3Client` or the `saveToTextFile` method for RDDs. There are two problems I face:

1. If I go with the `AmazonS3Client` I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException` since the code is sent from the Spark driver to the worker it needs to be serialized and apparently the the AmazonS3Client doesn't support that.
2. If I go with `saveToTextFile` I face a similar problem. When I go in the `foreachPartition` loop I need to I get `Iterable[T]` (in this case `p`) so if I want to use `saveToTextFile` I need to create an RDD of the Iterable hence the `parallelize`. The problem is that the SparkContext `sc` also (rightfully so) doesn't serialize.

`rdd.foreachPartition { p =>
  sc.parallelize(p.toSeq).saveAsTextFile(s"s3n://")
}`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to do that. You can just use `saveAsTextFile` with rdd:

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile(s"s3n://dir/to/aux/file")
```

`saveAsTextFile` will write to S3 in a folder with many parts of the file (as many parts as partitions). Then you can merge to a single file if you want:

```
  def mergeToS3(srcPath: String, dstPath: String, sc: SparkContext): Unit = {
    val hadoopConfig = sc.hadoopConfiguration
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(srcPath), hadoopConfig)
    FileUtil.copyMerge(fs, new Path(srcPath), fs, new Path(dstPath), true, hadoopConfig, null)
  }

  mergeToS3("s3n://dir/to/aux/file", "s3n://dir/to/singleFile",sc)
```